# angular 2+ bind string with variable in html

Tags: angular

i want to set value for input of component that contain string and value comes from server.what should i do?

I’ve tried something like this

```
<otk-title-value [title]="`پرداخت به ازای ${detailData?.stayingTime} شب`">
                        </otk-title-value>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try:

```
<otk-title-value title="پرداخت به ازای{{detailData?.stayingTime}} شب"></otk-title-value>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y2ppsn)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<otk-title-value [title]="'پرداخت به ازای' + detailData?.stayingTime + 'شب'"></otk-title-value>
```